# Changing the values of a drawing using excel or script

Tags: excel, pdf, pdf-generation, vba

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to change the measurement values of a AutoCAD drawing (plot/printed). I have 1 drawing with multiple parts, but the only thing that needs to be changed (almost weekly) and that is the values of some measurements for these parts.

[image: VIEW EXAMPLE HERE]

I've looked to Excel for a way to make a sheet where i can fill in these values and they get changed instantly. It can be an .PDF file that gets changed, the drawing needs to be printed anyway so no direct insert into AutoCAD needed.

Any tips or advice is welcome!

Cheers,
NvG

Comment: Always think of a PDF like being a already printed sheet of paper. It is very hard to change PDF files once they are generated. • Additionally there is no built in function in Excel to change PDF files so therefore it might be the wrong tool. • Consider making a PDF-Form from your PDF once you generated it, where you then can fill in the values every week and print/save that. This would be the easiest way I think.

Comment: AutoCAD seems to support vba programming (see [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/downloads/caas/downloads/content/download-the-microsoft-visual-basic-for-applications-module-vba.html) ), you might want to create a form directly in you AutoCAD project (I personally don't know AutoCAD)